# How to stop DataInputStream get byte[]?

Tags: java, sockets

I want to read and write `byte[]` data with a socket, but I cannot stop the stream.

This is my server:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Server side");
        DataInputStream in;
        DataOutputStream out;

        ServerSocket servers = null;
        Socket fromclient = null;

        // create server socket
        try {
            servers = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't listen to port 4444");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        try {
            System.out.print("Waiting for a client...");
            fromclient = servers.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't accept");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        in = new DataInputStream(fromclient.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(fromclient.getOutputStream());
        String input = "", output;

        System.out.println("Wait for messages");

        byte[] bytes = new byte[16*1024];

        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            byte[] mass = "some data".getBytes("UTF-8");
            out.write(mass, 0, count);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        fromclient.close();
        servers.close();
    }
}
```

When I receive data from the client it opens an infinite stream which doesn't stop.

How can I stop this `DataInputStream`?

Comment: "I cannot stop the stream" is not a problem description. Try again. NB `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));` should be `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes, 0, count));`,

Comment: "System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes, 0, count));" show error parameters

Answer (score 1):

Close the connection from the client side (or server side). As long as the connection is open, the server will wait for data to be sent.

In a proper setup you would have a well defined protocol, which could then include shutdown messages to inform the server when the client decides to disconnect. Simply closing the connection is a "raw" way to achieve that, but it's not very elegant.